# Unable to upload files with Selenium WebElement send_keys

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to automate file uploads using Selenium. I'm sending the file path to the `input` tag, but it isn't working.

After selection, I should be able to see the file and file size in a table, and, even though the files are being listed, its respective sizes are being listed as zero bytes. Then when the upload button is clicked nothing happens.

The code of the file input is the following:

```
<span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button" >
    <i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i>
    <span>Add files...&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
    <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
</span>
```

This is how I'm trying to upload the files:

```
file_input = driver.wait.until(ec.presence_of_element_located(
            (By.XPATH, "//input[@name=\"files[]\"]")))
file_input.send_keys(abspath(f))
```

[This is the result after running the script.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6Srq.png)

Any help is welcome. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's the site?

Comment: It is a private website. You would need credentials to see the page I'm talking about. If you are looking for something I didn't specify, you could tell me and  then I'll search it for you.

Comment: is the abspath(f) has been passed exactly? Did we get 0 size if we pass a file that doesn't actually exist?

Comment: Yes, the abspath(f) is being passed correctly. If, somehow we pass a file that doesn't exist the send_keys method would throw an exception.